# RxJava parallel threads wait for sequental thread

Tags: java, concurrency, rx-java

I got such a flow, where i need to prepare files in many threads and write to database in one thread

```
    Flowable.fromIterable(files)
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(prepareFiles())
            .doOnNext(writeToDatabase())
            .sequential()
            .takeUntil(file -> {
                return stopService.get();
            })
            .blockingSubscribe();
```

When i use such a flow it works perfectly. But i need to write to database in one thread (cause of database specifics)

So i just change two lines (`doOnNext` and `sequential`) in code and it became this:

```
    Flowable.fromIterable(files)
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(prepareFiles())
            .sequential()
            .doOnNext(writeToDatabase())
            .takeUntil(file -> {
                return stopService.get();
            })
            .blockingSubscribe();
```

But if you will look in JVM, you will see, that totaly speed became much slower

It seems, like all threads wait for only one thread for write into database

That the JVM with first code

[image]

And that is the JVM with the second code

[image]

You can see, that it seems like all threads wait for one

So, how to write in one thread, and set other threads not to wait for first?

Comment: So you basically want to submit a new task for the DB write and continue with the stream without waiting for the task to be processed?

Comment: Yes. I guess so. If you got a code solution. Please write it in simple answer

Comment: No, I don't have any ready to use code examples but I'd try to create an `ExecutorService` via `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, share the instance between the flows and submit tasks to it instead of directly writing to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is the effect of backpressure on `sequential`. Apply `observeOn` after it with another scheduler to not bog down the parallel threads.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/7394